Error on Martingale stategy Bot after upgrade
From a contact: Okay the bot is a Martingale strategy bot, It works well. The only problem is that after the upgrade of build number 1415 for mql4 the bot can't work on newer version so Is it possible to decompile it and add like an argument to make the bot works on newer version but not changing the strategy of how the bot works.
Can this be done without access to the source code? I have the files but not the source code.
I have no idea yet.
